# python: select a tab in the Tool Shelf

Tags: python

I'm trying to activate a specific tab in the tool shelf from a script.

The idea being that my add-on would setup an "enhanced/tailored" environment for the user when certain button is clicked.

Is that possible?

Also, following this idea, in the "Tools" tab of the tool shelf, there are many sections (i.e. Transform, Mesh Tools, Weight Tools...).
Is is possible to collapse/expand those sections from a script?